# How to send email intent without message?

Tags: android, kotlin, email, android-intent, deep-linking

I'm trying to open an email application from my app, without sending any message. I just want to open the app, but when I'm using

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL)
startActivity(intent)
```

I can't go back to my application. When Gmail app opens, and I press back button, the my application isn't even on the app list.
Is there any posibility to open the email app as another application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open Email app of sepreate stack

```
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

this intent will open the Main mail app make sure there is no draft in the mail app and it should work with you

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL);
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```